# Give an example of a bounded function on $[0,1]$, which doesnot achieve its infimum on any $[a,b] \subset [0,1], a < b$

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example  of a bounded function  on $[0,1]$, which doesnot achieve its  infimum on any $[a,b] \subset [0,1], a < b$

MY attempts :

i take    \begin{align}
 f(x)=\begin{cases}
  x &\text{ if } x\neq 0,1\\
  1/2 &\text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
\end{align}

Is   its  corrects  ??

Comment: $\text{Yes.}\hspace{0pt}$

Comment: thanks @TheoBendit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The infimum of $f$ is $0$ and the supremum is $1$, but no value of $x$ gives $0$ or $1$. So not only have you avoid the infimum, but also the supremum.